# How does OpenDNS know my real ip address even tho im connected to my vpn?

Tags: vpn, dns, opendns

I am connected to my VPN server (107.750.94.4), But it is also displaying my actual ISP address (210.246.xx.xxx).

How does it know my real ip address?

[image]

Comment: The answer, though slightly veiled, is right in front of you. Your VPN is not carrying your DNS requests (port 53) but is carrying http/https (port 80/443), so when your computer does a dns name lookup it is going directly out your Internet connection to resolve the IP address, but when you actually browse to the site it uses the VPN connection.

Comment: AKA, a dns leak when using your vpn.